# Need help defining variables from JSON formatted API response in Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm working on a program that calls a random API from PokeAPI and creates variables from the response for use as hints. I'm having problems with actually creating variables from the http response especially with the getJSONObject() method because I don't know what to put in the parenthesis. If anyone could show me how to define variables from this data, i would appreciate it. Thank You.
here is an example of the JSON data

```
  "id": 12,
  "name": "butterfree",
  "base_experience": 178,
  "height": 11,
  "is_default": true,
  "order": 16,
  "weight": 320,
  "abilities": [
    {
      "is_hidden": true,
      "slot": 3,
      "ability": {
        "name": "tinted-lens",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/110/"
      }
    }
```

and here is my attempt

````
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException {
        BufferedReader br;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Random random  = new Random();
        int randomPoke = random.nextInt(151)+1;
        String line;
        StringBuffer responseContent = new StringBuffer();
        String pokeURL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + randomPoke;
        URL url = new URL(pokeURL);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setReadTimeout(5000);
        con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(responseCode);
        if (responseCode > 299){
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                responseContent.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
        }else {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                responseContent.append(line);
            }
            br.close();

        }

        String json = gson.toJson(responseContent);
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(json.trim().charAt(0));
        //JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

        boolean isDefault = jo.getJSONObject(json).getBoolean("is_default");
        System.out.println(isDefault);
    } ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways to do this I have two proposals and I use only GSON lib

first

```
JsonElement element = JsonParser.parseString(json);
```

second

```
new Gson().fromJson(json, LinkedTreeMap.class);
```

I wrote the tests, maybe it'll help you more

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class PokemonTest {
  @Test
  public void parserWithJsonParser() {
    //given
    String json = getJson();
    Boolean isDefault = null;
    //when
    JsonElement element = JsonParser.parseString(json);
    if (element.isJsonObject()) {
      JsonObject asJsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject(); // is your Object
      JsonElement element1 = asJsonObject.get("is_default");
      if (element1.isJsonPrimitive()) {
        isDefault = element1.getAsBoolean();
      }
    }
    //then
    assertTrue(isDefault);
  }

  @Test
  public void parserWithMapOfObject() {
    //given
    String json = getJson();
    //when
    LinkedTreeMap<String, Object> linkedTreeMap = new Gson().fromJson(json, LinkedTreeMap.class);
    Boolean isDefault = (Boolean) linkedTreeMap.get("is_default");
    //then
    assertTrue(isDefault);
  }


  public String getJson() {
    return "{\n" +
            "  " +
            "\"id\": 12,\n" +
            "  \"name\": \"butterfree\",\n" +
            "  \"base_experience\": 178,\n" +
            "  \"height\": 11,\n" +
            "  \"is_default\": true,\n" +
            "  \"order\": 16,\n" +
            "  \"weight\": 320,\n" +
            "  \"abilities\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"is_hidden\": true,\n" +
            "      \"slot\": 3,\n" +
            "      \"ability\": {\n" +
            "        \"name\": \"tinted-lens\",\n" +
            "        \"url\": \"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/110/\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  ]\n" +
            "}";
  }
}
```

Comment: I see @2ook are new to "STACOVERFLOW"
if you think this answers your question please select "ACCEPTED" or "USEFUL" here you have an explanatory [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)